# socket.recv(buff) is receiving more data than buff

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu, tcp

Ok the question is already self explanatory, I'd add some details though. The same call e.g.

```
chunk=sock.recv(1024)
print sizeofChunk
```

happens to print the same expected result on windows that is 1024 but not on ubuntu. This is really outrageous, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for it to receive more than 1024 in one call, but it is possible that less would be received, so no 1024 is not an obvious 'expected' result. Please post your full code and clarify the 'more data than buff' problem.

Comment: Yes, where is sizeofChunk calculated